# Invoke-sqlcmd on remote machine

Tags: sql, powershell

I am using following code to execute a query on a remote machine.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $dbName -InputFile $filePath -U "test" -P "testpwd"
```

But getting an error like

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

My database server and my machine are in same domain but both are different machnies.
Please help.

Comment: What if you try `-U "mydomain\test"` ?

Comment: Are you using Powershell remoting on remote machine and then executing invoke-sqlcmd?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Windows Authentication and SQL Authentication switched on on the database server you are trying to access.!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am assuming that your `$serverInstance` variable is an object, instantiated in the following way:

`$serverInstance = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($SQLInstanceName)`

I believe that by the time you were having this issue you were using `IntegratedSecurity = true` (the default value). You can set this to false with the following assignment:

`$serverInstance.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure=$false;`

An explanation on how this solves the error you were having can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38644864/1198379):

> If your SQL Server is on one domain controller and you are trying to
>   connect to it from another domain controller then you will get this
>   error when
>
> ```
> IntegratedSecurity = true;
> ```
>
> This will happen even if you include a valid SQL Server username and
>   password in your connection string as they will automatically be
>   over-written with your windows login and password. Integrated security
>   means simply - use your windows credentials for login verification to
>   SQL Server. So, if you are logged in to a different domain controller
>   then it will fail. In the case where you are on two different domain
>   controllers then you have no choice but to use
>
> ```
> IntegratedSecurity = false;
> ```
>
> Now, when Integrated security is false SQL Server will use the SQL
>   Server login and password provided in your connection string. For this
>   to work, the SQL Server instance has to have its authentication mode
>   configured to mixed mode, being, SQL Server and Windows Authentication
>   mode.
>
> To verify or change this setting in SQL Server you can open the SQL
>   Server Management Studio and right-click on your server name and then
>   select Properties. On the pop-up that appears select Security and you
>   will see where to alter this setting if you need to.