# Trouble Connecting to sql server Login failed. "The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication"

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to host a SQL server database, but whenever I try to connect to it I get this error:

> The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows
>   authentication

I am connecting through Matlab using the following command:

```
conn = database('Clinical_Data','DoyleLab07\Acc','','com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver','jdbc:sqlserver://DOYLELAB07\SQLEXPRESS:54287;database=Clinical_Data;integratedSecurity=true;').
```

Connecting to the database using matlab worked fine as long as I was using matlab on the computer which I was using to host the server. However, when I use another computer and the same Matlab command I get the error I showed above.

When I look under control panel\system. I notice that no domain is listed on my host PC or the PC I am using to connect to the host, but both computers are in the same workgroup. Would I be able to fix my problem by creating a domain and adding the foreign PC and the host to that domain? If so, how can this be accomplished?

Any suggestions will be very much appreciated. 
Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: Note for anyone who finds this like I did:  this error can also be displayed for an incorrect password.

Comment: Yet another scenario this error can be displayed in is when the account you are using is locked.

Answer (score 60):

Getting rid of `Integrated Security=true` worked for me.

Comment: Readers - also see Jay's answer for an explanation of this flag.

Comment: For me, it worked by removing "Trusted_Connection=True" but your answer gave me a hint thanks

Answer (score 41):

In order to use Windows Authentication one of two things needs to be true:

1. You are executing from the same machine as the database server.
2. You have an Active Directory environment and the user the application is executing under (usually the logged in user) has rights to connect to that database.

If neither of those are true you have to do one of two things:

1. Establish a Windows Domain Controller, connect all of the relevant machines to that controller, then fix SQL server to use domain accounts; OR,
2. Change SQL server to use both Windows and SQL Server accounts.

By FAR the easiest way is to change SQL Server to use both Windows and SQL server accounts.  Then you just need to create a sql server user on the DB server and change your connection string to do that.

Best case option 1 will take a full day of installation and configuration.  Option 2 ought to take about 5 minutes.

Comment: I am having trouble with step 2. First off, I do not know how to change SQL Server to use both Windows and SQL sever accounts without reinstalling the server which I cannot do. Is there a way to do this in the configuration manager or in the Management Studio? Once I do this do I create the user through databases->security->Logins->New Login? What do you think I need to change in my login string? Is it the username and password? Because right now the user name "DoyleLab07\Acc" is the host computer.

Comment: @Gaven: Using management studio.  Right click on the server name.  Go to properties.  Click on the security tab.  Change "Server authentication" to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".  You might have to restart the SQL services.  Once done, connect to the db server, expand security and add an account.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393654/how-to-change-from-sql-server-windows-mode-to-mixed-modesql-server-2008

Comment: Is there a case where this won't work?  I've set SQL to use both, I've set integrated security to false and also tried removing it entirely while providing the correct user credentials.  Connecting over management studio works fine but through my app.config it fails with the above error.  Only similar question I can find is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724747/app-config-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain - which seems to have been solved with integrated security which isn't working in my case

Comment: apparently my issue mentioned above was caused by the order of the arguments? I didn't think this was an issue but its the only thing I changed and suddenly it worked...

Answer (score 39):

If your SQL Server is on one domain controller and you are trying to connect to it from another domain controller then you will get this error when

```
IntegratedSecurity = true;
```

This will happen even if you include a valid SQL Server username and password in your connection string as they will automatically be over-written with your windows login and password.  Integrated security means simply - use your windows credentials for login verification to SQL Server.  So, if you are logged in to a different domain controller then it will fail.  In the case where you are on two different domain controllers then you have no choice but to use

```
IntegratedSecurity = false;
```

Now, when Integrated security is false  SQL Server will use the SQL Server login and password provided in your connection string.  For this to work, the SQL Server instance has to have its authentication mode configured to mixed mode, being, SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.

To verify or change this setting in SQL Server you can open the SQL Server Management Studio and right-click on your server name and then select Properties.  On the pop-up that appears select Security and you will see where to alter this setting if you need to.

Comment: But what if we don't have SQL server credential. Some client just provide the Windows authentication.  And what is not good creating Registry Editor entry of DisableLoopbackCheck  ?

Answer (score 15):

I've had this same issue when using DNS aliases and hosts files to connect to a machine using a different domain name.

Say you have a SQL server called `sql1` on `mydomain.com` - which is an Active Directory domain - and you also have a DNS zone for mydomain.net, and - for consistency - you set up a DNS alias (CNAME) record for `database.mydomain.net --> sql1.mydomain.com`

You'll be able to connect to `sql1.mydomain.com` using Windows integrated security, but won't be able to connect to `database.mydomain.net` **even though it's the same server** because the domain name doesn't match your AD domain.

Comment: Good point, I have seen these types of name mismatches before when I used to work on the help desk.

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the issue while connecting to SQL Always On Listener. Disabling the loop back check resolved the issue.

1. Edit the registry using regedit. (Start –> Run > Regedit )
2. Navigate to: `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA`
3. Add a `DWORD` value called `“DisableLoopbackCheck”`
4. Set this value to `1`

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/04/18/sql-server-login-failed-login-untrusted-domain-cannot-used-windows-authentication/

Answer (score 10):

This error message can also occur if the account you are using to access the SQL server is locked out by the domain.

Comment: Yes, for example, a Service Account was created, but they forgot tick the "Password Never Expires" box!

Comment: Yes, in my case, the error started occurring after the password was changed on the database account.  It turns out that a web application using the old password was still deployed, causing the account to get repeatedly locked out.  We finally resolved it by undeploying the webapp that still had the old password.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/04/18/sql-server-login-failed-login-untrusted-domain-cannot-used-windows-authentication/), you might need to disable the loopback

Loopback check can be removed by adding a registry entry as follows:

- Edit the registry using regedit. (Start –> Run > Regedit )
- Navigate to: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA
- Add a DWORD value called “DisableLoopbackCheck” Set this value to 1

Answer (score 5):

If you using windows authentication make sure that password of the user hasn't expired. An expired password can explain this error. This was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 4):

***Why not use a SQL Server account and pass both the user name and password?***

Here is the reason why.

In short, it looks like you have an authentication issue.

The problem with workgroups is there is no common Access Control List like Active Directory (AD).  If you are using ODBC or JDBC, the wrong credentials are passed.

Even if you create a local windows account (LWA) on the machine (SE) that has SQL Express installed (SE\LWA), the credentials that will be passed from your client machine (CM) will be CM\LWA.

Answer (score 3):

#### Same Error with Connection String in Visual Studio dev environment

Our development database server was recently given a self-signed certificate so it automatically became untrusted. This resulted in the login error cited above. I added `TrustServerCertificate=True` to my connection string and it works now.

`"Server=TheServerAddress; Database=TheDataBase; User Id=TheUsername; Password=ThePassword; TrustServerCertificate=True"`

NOTE: This certificate configuration is not recommended for production environments.

Answer (score 2):

i removed `Integrated Security=true` and `Trusted_Connection=True` both of them , worked for me..

Answer (score 1):

In my case the Aliases within SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration were pointing to invalid server/IP. Once updated it worked correctly.

To check:
1. Start "SQL Server Configuration Manager"
2. Navigate to "SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration" and then "Aliases"
3. Ensure "Alias Name" and "Server" match correctly for TCP/IP

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me to get access from another machine to SQL Server using Windows Authentication. This approach may be useful only in development/test environment. E.g. you need to update password manually once you change it on your working machine.

On machine with SQL Server go to Control Panel and add new Windows User with same username and password as is on your working machine. Then create SQL Server login for this user:

```
CREATE LOGIN [SQLSERVERHOST\myuser] FROM WINDOWS;
```

Now you can use this login for Windows Authentication.

If you receive error 'The login is from an untrusted domain', this may mean that you changed password on your working machine and now need to update password on SQL Server machine.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my suggestion for a resolution, I had a copy of a VM server for developing and testing, I created the database on that with 'sa' having ownership on the db.

I then restored the database onto the live VM server but I was getting the same error mentioned even though the data was still returning correctly.  I looked up the 'sa' user mappings and could see it wasn't mapped to the database when I tried to apply the mapping I got a another error "Fix: Cannot use the special principal ‘sa’. Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15405".  so I ran this instead

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::dbname  TO sa

I rechecked the user mappings and it was now assigned to my db and it fixed a lot of access issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

Joining a WORKGROUP then rejoining the domain fixed this issue for me.

I got this error while using Virtual Box VM's. The issue started to happen when I moved the VM files to a new drive location or computer.

Hope this helps the VM folks.

Answer (score 0):

We now use a privileged account management solution that changes our passwords regularly.  I ended up receiving this error after my password was changed.  Closing and re-opening SSMS with the new password resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I started to get this error when i tried to login to SSMS using 'windows Authentication'. This started to happen after i renamed the Windows SQL server. I tried everything to resolve this error and in my particular case changing the machine names in the 'hosts' file to reflect the name SQL server name change resolved the issue.   C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because we where using a DNS name from an old server, ponting to a new server. Using the newserver\inst1 address, worked. both newserver\inst1 and oldserver\inst1 pointed to the same IP.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another thing to check:
We had our nightly QA restore job stop working all of a sudden after another developer remoted into the QA server and tried to start the restore job during the middle of the day, which subsequently failed with the "untrusted domain" message. Somehow the server pointed to be the job's maintenance plan was (changed?) using the ip address, instead of the local machine's name. Upon replacing with the machine name the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In .net Core also you may get this error if Trusted_Connection=True;
Is set.  Sample  setting in appsettings.json

```
ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=serverName; Database=DbName; uid=userId; pwd=password; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

},

Answer (score 0):

I enabled Trust Server Certificate in the Connection Properties and it worked for me

[image: connection properties]

Comment: Did not work for me. The DisableLoopbackCheck workaround from previous comment worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You might find out that you have more than one connection string, and you forgot to change the other one to Integrated Security to false. It happened to me. This answer might help someone.

I was focusing on the web config and the access rights, after a long hustle i remembered that I have another connection string in one of my classes for the emails, I had to change the connection string on the class to use the web config one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sometime SSMS hang and close all of sudden ,then you get below error when you reconnect to SSMS

i) The Login is From an Untrusted Domain and Cannot be Used with Windows Authentication

OR

ii) The target principal name is incorrect .Cannot generate SSPI context.

In both cases `RESTART YOUR MACHINE`.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Use This Connection URL It's Work Fine
"Data Source=Your IP Address;Initial Catalog = DatabaseName;User ID =sa;Password =your PassWord;TrustServerCertificate=True"**

Example : "Data Source=192.168.150.122;Initial Catalog=StudentDb;User ID=sa; PassWord=123;TrustServerCertificate=True"

Comment: This answer is pretty much the same as an earlier one which recommended using username/password to connect to the db instead of Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

add TrustServerCertificate="true"

similar option in MSSMS

also in command line run

```
ipconfig /flushdns
klist purge
```

Answer (score 0):

changing the **IP address** to **machine name** worked for me

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

If you have two servers on the same domain (eg. APP and DB), you can also use Windows Authentication between the app and MSSQL by setting up local users on both machines that match (same username and password). If you don't have the passwords matched up, it can throw this error.

Answer (score -2):

Following was working for me. hope this helps you

```
<add name="getconn" connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***" />
```

Comment: Of course that _worked_, but only because you turned OFF "Windows authentication".