# App Config - The Login is from an untrusted domain

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string, app-config

First, I try to connect to sql server of other computer(PC1-PC\Instance1) through ssms with Windows Authentication but got this error

`Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.`

I resolve the error when I edit the password of sa to `1234` in PC1-PC\Instance1. Then connect in the ssms with SQL Server Authentication. And successfully connected.

The problem is in my Winforms app config, I set the connection to this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LibrarySystem.Properties.Settings.LibraryConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PC1-PC\Instance1;
     Initial Catalog=System1;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User id = sa;Password = 1234" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

But I got this error `Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<connectionStrings><add name="LibrarySystem.Properties.Settings.LibraryConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PC1-PC\Instance1;
 Initial Catalog=System1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User id = sa;Password = 1234" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: this worked for you?  I'm having the same issue where I can connect no problem by SSMS, yet through the config I get the untrusted domain messaged.  I've tried changing the Integrated security setting to false and also removing it entirely.

Comment: Order of the arguments appeared to be my issue above