# Windows authetication issues"The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2016, trust

My domains actually trust each other because I have access from both sides and can log in with Sql authentication. But when I try to access it with windows authentication it gives the "Login failed. The login is from a Un- trusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)" error. Plus the sql server accepts sql and windows auth.

Thanks

Comment: *can log in with sql authentication* - This just requires a route to the server and valid credentials; there is no domain based trust or negotiation involved.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603696/trouble-connecting-to-sql-server-login-failed-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-d/45333508#45333508

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me. In web.config, when I checked **connectionString** it was set to **Integrated Security=true**. Make **Integrated Security=false** if you are providing the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to resolve this problem. One is to use RUNAS command. Another way to use credential manager in windows. The main problem here is your computer is in one domain and the SQL SERVER is another domain. SQL SERVER doesn't allow due to security issue. See [Doc](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3250/connect-to-sql-servers-in-another-domain-using-windows-authentication/) for more details