# Make SQL Server database connection using python with windows authentication

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, adodbapi

I am using `adodbapi` library for database connection to SQL Server.

My below connection string works perfect with SQL Server authentication-

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("C:/configsql.ini")
_SERVER_NAME = config['SQL']['SERVER_NAME']
_DATABASE = config['SQL']['DATABASE']
_USERNAME = config['SQL']['USERNAME']
_PASSWORD = config['SQL']['PASSWORD']
conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source={0};Database={1};UID={2};PWD={3};".format(_SERVER_NAME,_DATABASE,_USERNAME,_PASSWORD))
return conn
```

When I try to perform connection using windows authentication it does not works.

I modified connection string as below:

```
conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False".format(_SERVER_NAME,_DATABASE))
```

and I'm getting this exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 113, in connect
>
> co.connect(kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 275, in connect
>
> self.connector.Open()  # Open the ADO connection
>
> File "", line 3, in Open
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in *ApplyTypes*
>
> result = self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
>
> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server', 'Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.', None, 0, -2147467259), None)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "Workflow.py", line 47, in sql_connection
>
> conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False".format(_SERVER_NAME,_DATABASE))
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 117, in connect
>
> raise api.OperationalError(e, message)
>
> adodbapi.apibase.OperationalError: (com_error(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server', 'Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.', None, 0, -2147467259), None), 'Error opening connection to "PROVIDER=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=TESTSERVER;Database=TEST;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False"')

Please can anyone let me know how to make connection with SQL Server using Windows authentication?

Comment: Could you also post the code and connection string that does not work?  And also the error message you get.

Comment: Added modified connection string and exception.

Comment: The error is: "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication."

Comment: There are lots of potential answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603696/trouble-connecting-to-sql-server-login-failed-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-d

Comment: But usually this error means exactly what it says.  You are attempting to connect to a server from a local account on another computer, or a domain account from a domain that is not trusted by the SQL Server.

Comment: Ohk. It is correct as you mentioned. How do I resolve it?

Comment: You have to connect from a Windows account which is a member of, or otherwise trusted by, the domain which the SQL Server machine is a member of.