# Connecting to SQL Server with pyodbc, FreeTDS, and Kerberos authentication on macOS

Tags: macos, database-connection, kerberos, pyodbc, freetds

I never ask questions to forums, as I can generally find the answer somewhere on the interweb.
However, in this instance I cannot.

Summary: I can connect to and query the database with kerberos authentication via Azure Data Studio and tsql with FreeTDS.  I cannot connect to the pyodbc.  I've tried tens of different configurations with no success.

My ultimate goal is to connect to the MSSQL server DB with python.

Thank you for any input.

**Background**

local machine macOS 10.15.4
Connected to VPN required for kerberos authentication
Have successfully queried DB from Azure Data Studio
database is Microsoft SQL Server 2016

**FreeTDS**

tsql -S  -U 'directory\username' -> Works, can query DB

**isql**

isql dsn_name 'directory\username' 'password'

error DIAG [42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

isql dsn_name 'directory\username'

error: DIAG [42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

**pyodbc**

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=dsn_name;Trusted_Connection=yes')

error: 
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (18452) (SQLDriverConnect)')

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=dsn_name;UID=directory\username;PWD="password"')

error: 
DIAG [01000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Adaptive Server connection failed
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

**Configuration**

**krb5.conf**

libdefaults

default_realm = domain

[realms]

domain_same_as_default = {

kdc = kdc_address

}

**odbc.ini**

[dsn_name]

Description             = MSSQL Server

Driver                  = FreeTDS

Servername              = server_name

**odbcinst.ini**

[FreeTDS]

Description=FreeTDS Driver for Linux & MSSQL

Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so

Setup=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so

UsageCount=1

[ODBC]
Trace=Yes

TraceFile=/dev/stdout

**freetds.conf**

[server_name]
host                            = ip_address

port                            = port_num

database                        = db_name

REALM                           = DOMAIN

Answer (score 1):

I've avoided using DSNs with `pyodbc`, as I prefer to have all my configuration in one spot. Here's an example connection string I use with a domain.

```py
con = pyodbc.connect(
    r"DRIVER={FreeTDS};"
    r'SERVER=mssql.mydomain.com;'
    r"PORT=1433;"
    r"DATABASE=my_db;"
    f"UID=MYDOMAIN\\my_username;"
    f"PWD=my_password;"
    r"TDS_Version=7.3;"
    r"Encrypt=yes;"
    r"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)
```

Give that a whirl? The two backslashes (`\\`) are needed for escaping if using Windows domain auth, that is not a typo. The key thing you may be missing is `TDS_Version`. You can read more about TDS Versions here: https://www.freetds.org/userguide/ChoosingTdsProtocol.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the input.  With this modification I get the following error: "Adaptive Server connection failed"

Comment: So I have two non-ideal ideas. (1) If you can, create a SQL Server auth account to connect with rather than a Windows auth account. It is always a better idea. Microsoft's own Linux driver doesn't support Windows auth, only FreeTDS does. (2) Check this thread for some ideas on the error you're getting from `isql`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603696/trouble-connecting-to-sql-server-login-failed-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-d

Comment: Thank you for the direction!