# Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, xamarin.forms

getting {"Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication."} please give any suggetion why this error is throwing.

```
  public int Find(string AccountNumber, DateTime DepositedDT)
        {
            IsPigmySync pigmySync = new IsPigmySync();
            pigmySync.AccountNumber = AccountNumber;
            pigmySync.DepositedDT = DepositedDT;

            SqlParameter issynced = new SqlParameter("@p2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            issynced.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            try
            {
                var sql = "exec Pigmy_GetPigmyItems @p0,@p1,@p2 OUT";

                
               // var result = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated(sqlQuery);
                var result = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, pigmySync.AccountNumber, pigmySync.DepositedDT, issynced);
                int ab = result;
                pigmySync.IsSynced = (int)issynced.Value;

                return pigmySync.IsSynced;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return 0;
            }
```

above is my code snippet. using entity framework,xamarin forms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble Connecting to sql server Login failed. "The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603696/trouble-connecting-to-sql-server-login-failed-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-d)

Comment: For me, it worked by removing "Trusted_Connection=True"

Answer (score 0):

An old post but I'll add my solution.  My scenario is that I have two AD domains, one on the internal lan and one on the DMZ.  The domains are separate but the accounts shadow each other (each user has the same username and password on each domain).  The lan can authenticate with the sql server on the DMZ using windows authentication.  (It has been working for over 20 years). Suddenly I got the above error for one user.  The user has an azure AD for the lan domain.  I believe the error occurred when I added the azure AD user to the DMZ as a new user but I'm not sure this caused the issue.  Anyway I deleted both accounts from the DMZ domain and added back the lan user to the DMZ domain and the error disappeared.